# How to use @nuxt/content inside Component?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js, nuxt-content

I'm trying to nuxt-contnt inside a component it works well in page with asyncData but not working inside the component

this works fine :

```
export default {
 async asyncData({ $content }) {
 const page = await $content('hello').fetch()

 return {
   page,
  }
 },
}
```

but this is not working :

```
 export default {
 data() {
  return {
  content: [],
 }
 },
 async fetch({ $content }) {
  this.content = await $content('hello').fetch()

 },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetch` doesn't have any parameters but has access to `this`, so it should be

```js
async fetch() {
  this.content = await this.$content('hello').fetch()
 }
```

https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/data-fetching/